# Finding the max of average in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List = new List();

```
public class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public string marks { get; set; }
}
```

My Objective

Find the Student with the Highest Average

**Adding the data sample**

```
i.Add(new List<Student> { Id=1,Name= "Maddy",Subject="English",Marks=87 };
i.Add(new List<Student> { Id=1,Name= "Maddy",Subject="Science",Marks=81 };
i.Add(new List<Student> { Id=2,Name= "Mathew",Subject="Maths",Marks=83 };
i.Add(new List<Student> { Id=2,Name= "Mathew",Subject="Science",Marks=80 };
```

**What I tried**

```
var x=  i.GroupBy(i=>i.Id)
         .Select( g=> new 
                     { 
                       MaxAverage= g.Max(g.Average(i=>i.Marks))  
                      }
```

Comment: As a hint, you're looking to work out the average for every student, then pick the First from an the students Ordered by their average.

Comment: Is `marks` a `string` or an `int`? What should be the output, the student ID, or Name, or what?

Comment: You should try to do it without Linq first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using Linq "query syntax"

  ```
  var best = from student in students
             group student by student.Id into studentAverage
             let average = studentAverage.Average (s => s.Marks)
             orderby average descending
             select new { id = studentAverage.Key, average };
             // change projection to have only id or average
  ```
- Using Linq "method syntax"

  ```
  var best =
      students
      .GroupBy (student => student.Id,
                student => student.Marks,
                (id, marks) => new { id, average = marks.Average () })
      .OrderByDescending (studentAverage => studentAverage.average)
      // add a projection (Select) here to have only id or average
      .FirstOrDefault ();
  ```

  Maybe simpler alternative but more oriented toward getting only the Id

  ```
  var best =
      students
      .ToLookup (s => s.Id, s => s.Marks)
      .OrderByDescending (marksById => marksById.Average ())
      .FirstOrDefault ();

  // Key will contain the Id but Average must be calculated again
  // var avg = best.Average();
  ```
- Using "classic" code (longer, but clearer steps)

  ```
  var studentMarks = new Dictionary<int, List<double>> (students.Count);

  foreach (var student in students)
  {
      int id = student.Id;
      List<double> marks;

      if (!studentMarks.TryGetValue (id, out marks))
      {
          marks = new List<double> ();
          studentMarks.Add (id, marks);
      }

      marks.Add (student.Marks);
  }

  double? bestAverage = null;
  int? idOfBest = null;

  foreach (var idAndMarks in studentMarks)
  {
      var average = 0.0;

      foreach (var mark in idAndMarks.Value)
      {
          average += mark;
      }

      average /= idAndMarks.Value.Count;

      if (average > bestAverage)
      {
          bestAverage = average;
          idOfBest = idAndMarks.Key;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: you will need to update the if block in the first foreach with this ... `studentMarks.Add(id, marks = new List<double>())`  ... otherwise you will get exceptions from marks not being set on the first pass for each new Id.

Answer (score 2):

**Best Student**

```
var best = i.GroupBy(g => g.Id)
            .Select(g => new { 
                StudentID = g.Key, 
                Name = g.First().Name, 
                Average = g.Average(m => m.Marks), 
                })
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Average)
            .First();
// best = { StudentID = 1, Name = Maddy, Average = 84 }
```

**Best Average**

```
var best = i.GroupBy(g => g.Id)
            .Select(g => g.Average(m => m.Marks))
            .Max();
// best = 84.0
```

**Query Syntax** (just because)

```
var best = (from student in 
                from grade in grades 
                group grade by grade.Id
             select student.Average(mark=>mark.Marks)).Max();    
// best = 84.0
```

**Without LINQ** (I saw a comment suggesting you do it this way... ouch)

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<double>>();
foreach (var g in i )
{
    var id = g.Id;
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(id))
        dict.Add(id, new List<double>());
    dict[id].Add(g.Marks);
}
double best = 0.0;
foreach (var g in dict)
{
    var totalmarks = 0.0;
    foreach (var mark in g.Value)
    {
        totalmarks += (double)mark;
    }
    var average = totalmarks / g.Value.Count;
    if (best < average)
        best = average;
}
// best = 84.0
```

**Without LINQ (slightly optimized)**

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, double>>();
foreach (var g in i)
{
    var id = g.Id;
    Tuple<int, double> t;
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(id))
        dict.Add(id, t = Tuple.Create(0, 0.0));
    else
        t = dict[id];
    var c = t.Item1 + 1;

    dict[id] =  Tuple.Create(c, (t.Item2 * t.Item1 + g.Marks) / c);
}
double best = 0.0;
foreach (var g in dict)
{
    var m = g.Value.Item2;
    if (best < m)
        best = m;
}
// best = 84.0
```

Comment: Your query syntax version is invalid.  You're doing a projection after a group by so you need to give a name for the group and use it.

Comment: Oh, the way you wrote it, I suppose it would work. I didn't realize that `student` referred to the groups and you had "nested" queries.

Comment: the `group by` query returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, a'>>` where the key is the ID and the `a'` is the original record.  the outer `from` iterates over the grouping per key allowing the average to me selected for each ID.  (returning `IEnumerable<double>`) which is then stuffed into `.Max()` to get the final result. it looks nasty but it works.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I kicked it on its own line.  it looked really, really bad when I had both froms on the same line.

Comment: The way I would have written that would be like this (which is very similar and exactly equivalent): `(from grade in grades group grade by grade.Id into g select g.Average(mark=>mark.Marks)).Max()`

Comment: The optimized version can result in loss of precision with the various multiplication and division using double values. Also consider replacing the `ContainsKey` block by `TryGetValue`

Comment: trueish on the resolution... the lost precision is so tiny (and pretty much none existent if none of the inputs as decimals to start with).  And the `TryGetValue doesn't really add anything useful (your example has a bug)

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = new List<Student>();

i.Add(new Student { Id = 1, Name = "Maddy", Subject = "English", Marks = 87 });
i.Add(new Student { Id = 1, Name = "Maddy", Subject = "Science", Marks = 81 });
i.Add(new Student { Id = 2, Name = "Mathew", Subject = "Maths", Marks = 83 });
i.Add(new Student { Id = 2, Name = "Mathew", Subject = "Science", Marks = 80 });


var students = i.GroupBy(p => p.Id).ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Select(p => p.Marks).Average());
var maxStudent = students.Aggregate((l, r) => l.Value > r.Value ? l : r).Key;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
 var bestStudent = i.GroupBy(i=>i.Id)
    .Select( g=> new Student 
    { 
        Id = g.Key, 
        Name = g.First().Name, 
        Marks = g.Average(i=>i.Marks)) 
    })
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.Marks)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: that would give you the worst ;)

Comment: no problem... I had the same code on my first test :)

Comment: great minds think alike, as my mother always says :)